# Save Logs to use it again , mysql database

Tags: mysql

I working on hotspot system and that system has logs table which contain information about every user in that system like(username, ip address, macaddress , login date); and this information may will be important in one date , but that table is filled in short time and has many and many record in it , so I must to clear it without loss the information on it , what do think should I do to solve it ?
should I make an a backup   for that table every day?
so  if I want to access record in that table I must to restore it and access that record. I don't believe with that solution , can you  give suggest

Comment: How much is `has many and many record`?

Comment: IT MAY BE 10,000 RECORDS IN ONE DATE

Comment: So it's not that big. Why you clear it if you need this information? Can you use file logs?

Comment: percona-toolkit has utility called pt-archiver, which can archive MySQL table without losing data and stores it as a file or into another db/server. You can run it as a cron job daily. But you still need to restore specific day's backup into some temporary table if required.